# Using sed with delimiters similar to cut

Tags: bash, macos, shell, awk, sed

Given a file `foo.txt` containing file names such as:

```
2015_275_14_1,Siboney_by_The_Tailor_Maids
2015_275_16_1,Louis_Armstrong_Cant_Give_You_Anything_But_Love
2015_275_17_1,Benny_Goodman_Trio_Nice_Work_Avalon
2015_275_18_1,Feather_On_Jazz_Jazz_In_The_Concert_Hall
2015_235_1_1,Integration_Report_1
2015_273_2_1_1,Cab_Calloway_Home_Movie_1
2015_273_2_2_1,Cab_Calloway_Home_Movie_2
```

I want to replace the `_` in the part before the comma with `.` and the `_` in the second part after the comma with a space.

I can accomplish each individually with:

```
sed -E -i '' 's/([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{3})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9])/\1.\2.\3.\4./'
```

for the first part, and the second part then with:

```
sed -E -i '' "s/_/ /g"
```

But I was hoping to accomplish it in an easier fashion by using cut with sed but that doesn't work:

`cut -d "," -f 1 foo.txt | sed -E -i '' "s/_/./g" foo.txt && cut -d "," -f 2 foo.txt | sed -E -i '' "s/_/ /g" foo.txt`

No good.

So, is there a way to accomplish this with `sed` or maybe `awk` or maybe something else where I'm treating the `,` as  a delimiter such as in `cut`?

Desired output:

```
2015.275.14.1,Siboney by The Tailor Maids
```

Comment: You may give the expected output for more detailed information.

Comment: @CWLiu ok. Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [@CWLiu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44837684/7381355)'s answer but I use OFS (output field separator) instead of adding back in the comma and having to add newline from using printf.

```
awk -F ',' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {gsub(/_/, ".", $1); gsub(/_/, " ", $2); print;}' foo.txt
```

Explanation:

`-F ','` sets the field separator

`BEGIN {OFS = FS}` sets the output field separator (default space) equal to the field separator so the comma is printed back out

`gsub(/_/, ".", $1)` global substitution on the first column

`gsub(/_/, " ", $2)` global substitution on the second column

`print` print the whole line

Comment: Thank you! @dosentmatter excellent explanation! Also thank you to edmorton and benjaminw and CWliu for the answers. Great job everyone!

Comment: Just be aware that the first arg to `gsub()` is a regexp, not a string, so the code should be using regexp delimiters (`/.../`) not string delimiters (`"..."`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` to attain your goal, here's the method.

```
$ awk -F',' '{gsub(/_/,".",$1);gsub(/_/," ",$2);printf "%s,%s\n",$1,$2}' file                                                                                                    
2015.275.14.1,Siboney by The Tailor Maids
2015.275.16.1,Louis Armstrong Cant Give You Anything But Love
2015.275.17.1,Benny Goodman Trio Nice Work Avalon
2015.275.18.1,Feather On Jazz Jazz In The Concert Hall
2015.235.1.1,Integration Report 1
2015.273.2.1.1,Cab Calloway Home Movie 1
2015.273.2.2.1,Cab Calloway Home Movie 2
```

Comment: Thank you @CWLiu Great job everyone!

Comment: @Bleakley, you may check to accept the answer if your problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could `cut` and `paste`:

```
$ paste -d, <(cut -d, -f1 infile | sed 'y/_/./') <(cut -d, -f2 infile | sed 'y/_/ /')
2015.275.14.1,Siboney by The Tailor Maids
2015.275.16.1,Louis Armstrong Cant Give You Anything But Love
2015.275.17.1,Benny Goodman Trio Nice Work Avalon
2015.275.18.1,Feather On Jazz Jazz In The Concert Hall
2015.235.1.1,Integration Report 1
2015.273.2.1.1,Cab Calloway Home Movie 1
2015.273.2.2.1,Cab Calloway Home Movie 2
```

The process substitution `<()` lets you treat the output of commands like a file, and `paste -d,` pastes the output of each command side-by-side, separated by a comma.

The sed `y` command transliterates characters and is, in this case, equivalent to `s/_/./g`. and `s/_/ /g`.

You could also do it purely in sed, but it's a bit unwieldy:

```
sed 'h;s/.*,//;y/_/ /;x;s/,.*//;y/_/./;G;s/\n/,/' infile
```

Explained:

```
h         # Copy pattern space to hold space
s/.*,//   # Remove first part including comma
y/_/ /    # Replace all "_" by spaces in the remaining second part
x         # Swap pattern and hold space
s/,.*//   # Remove second part including comma
y/_/./    # Replace all "_" by periods in the remaining first part
G         # Append hold space to pattern space
s/\n/,/   # Replace linebreak with comma
```

Or, alternatively (from comment by [potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong)):

```
sed 's/,/\n/;h;y/_/ /;x;y/_/./;G;s/\n.*\n/,/'  infile
```

Explained:

```
s/,/\n/      # Replace comma by linebreak
h            # Copy pattern space to hold space
y/_/ /       # Replace all "_" by spaces
x            # Swap pattern and hold space
y/_/./       # Replace all "_" by periods
G            # Append hold space
s/\n.*\n/,/  # Remove second and third line in pattern space
```

Comment: An alternative for the sed solution might be: `sed 's/,/\n/;h;y/_/ /;x;y/_/./;G;s/\n.*\n/,/' file`

Comment: @potong Nice, let me add that!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/_/,".",$1); gsub(/_/," ",$2)} 1' file
2015.275.14.1,Siboney by The Tailor Maids
2015.275.16.1,Louis Armstrong Cant Give You Anything But Love
2015.275.17.1,Benny Goodman Trio Nice Work Avalon
2015.275.18.1,Feather On Jazz Jazz In The Concert Hall
2015.235.1.1,Integration Report 1
2015.273.2.1.1,Cab Calloway Home Movie 1
2015.273.2.2.1,Cab Calloway Home Movie 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for `GNU sed`:

```
$ cat input.txt 
2015_275_14_1,Siboney_by_The_Tailor_Maids
2015_275_16_1,Louis_Armstrong_Cant_Give_You_Anything_But_Love
2015_275_17_1,Benny_Goodman_Trio_Nice_Work_Avalon
2015_275_18_1,Feather_On_Jazz_Jazz_In_The_Concert_Hall
2015_235_1_1,Integration_Report_1
2015_273_2_1_1,Cab_Calloway_Home_Movie_1
2015_273_2_2_1,Cab_Calloway_Home_Movie_2
$ sed -r ':loop;/^[^_]+,/{s/_/ /g;bend};s/_/./;bloop;:end' input.txt
2015.275.14.1,Siboney by The Tailor Maids
2015.275.16.1,Louis Armstrong Cant Give You Anything But Love
2015.275.17.1,Benny Goodman Trio Nice Work Avalon
2015.275.18.1,Feather On Jazz Jazz In The Concert Hall
2015.235.1.1,Integration Report 1
2015.273.2.1.1,Cab Calloway Home Movie 1
2015.273.2.2.1,Cab Calloway Home Movie 2
```

Explanation:

1. use `s/_/./` to substitute `_` to `.` until all `_` before `,` have been substituted, which is judged by `^[^_]+,`;
2. then, if `^[^_]+,` matches, use `s/_/ /g` to subtitute all `_` to  after `,`